# What is the intensity of this light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, scattering, classical-electrodynamics

I am struggling with a derivation that calculates the cross sections for Mie scattering and since the incident light is considered to be a x-polarized plane wave I thought that we would have $$I_i = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}} \vert E_0 \vert^2$$, but I do not understand this derivation then, since a factor $2 \pi $ seems to be missing.

It starts with an expression for the scattered field, explains how they got this expression by using some orthogonality properties and then - in my opinion argue - that this $Re(g_n)=1$. But then I do not understand what they take as the incident intensity in order to get the expression $C_{sca}$. Does anybody have an idea?

> $$
>  W_s=\frac{\pi|E_0|^2}{k\omega\mu}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n+1)\mathcal{Re}\{g_n\}(|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2),
> $$ where we have used (4.24) and the relation $$
>  \int_0^\pi(\pi_n\pi_m+\tau_n\tau_m)\sin{\theta}\text{
>  }d\theta=\delta_{n\text{ }m}\frac{2n^2(n+1)^2}{2n+1}, $$ which follows
>   from (4.27). The quantity $g_n$, is defined as - $i\xi_n^*\xi_n^{'}$,
>   may be written in form $$
>  g_n=(\chi_n^*\psi_n^{'}-\psi_n^*\chi_n^{'})-i(\psi_n^*\psi_n^{'}+\chi_n^*\chi_n^{'}),
>  $$ where the Riccati-Bessel function $\chi_n$ is - $\rho y_n(\rho)$
>   and, therefore, $\xi_n=\psi_n-i\chi_n$. The functions $\psi_n$ and
>    $\chi_n$ are real for real argument; therefore, if we use the
>   Wronskian(Antosiewicz, 1964) $$
>  \chi_n\psi_n^{'}-\psi_n\chi_n^{'}=1,\tag{4.60} $$ it follows that the
>   scattering cross section is $$
>  C_{sca}=\frac{W_s}{I_i}=\frac{2\pi}{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n+1)(|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2).\tag{4.61}
>  $$

Comment: Which book is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add this as a comment but dont have enough rep, so please dont downvote me lol, but the incident intensity comes from the expansion coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$. Look further back in the book to see the equation they appear in.